# Datagrid CanUserAddRows

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

In a WPF in using datagrid to add data from database. 
datagrid XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsManipulationEnabled="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Middle Name" Binding="{Binding Path=MiddleName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200"/>           
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In binding datagrid to ObservableCollection. The goal is to add data but when im starting my application datagrid is empty with no opportunity for editing.

Viewmodel part.

```
private ObservableCollection<Other> _children;
    public ObservableCollection<Other> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Children");
        }
    }
```

EDM autogenerated class.

```
public partial class Other
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you generate collection

Comment: Can we see your code, i.e. what are you binding to? Are you getting any binding errors?  Have you debugged to see if the data is getting fetched from the database?  What have you done so far to investigate this problem?

Comment: where do you set the value to the collection?

Comment: the goal is not to get data from database, i want to add it. CanUserReorderColumns="True" but datagrid is not editable.

Comment: you want to add new row?

Comment: I want to add rows in datagrid and then save it to db.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that You set collection to Children Collection Using public Setter
2. make sure that Your binding is correct ( in case of problem You will se details in Visual Stucio Output.
3. To be certain that Your binding will work Please implement IProperytyChanged interface in your Other class